# WooCommerce problem with SOME orders being paid for yet still having status 'Pending Order'

Tags: woocommerce, worldpay

Receiving orders in the WooCommerce backend and some of these are 'Pending'. Most of these are abandoned orders, some are failed transactions, but some are not.

When I go to the WorldPay transaction page, the order is authorised/paid, but WooCommerce hasn't received the authorisation and so doesn't update the order. This was about 1% of the total orders taken, but happening more frequently recently.

The site less busy now as competitors have opened up, but numbers of these unauthorised orders are increasing.

My question is this: 1. What is causing this? Is it the server? 2. How many orders does WooCommerce normally lose as a percentage of total?